# Django - Annotation dictionary does not display correctly in template

Tags: python, django

I got these models in my models.py

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    stars = models.IntegerField()
    user_rating = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="rater", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_rated = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="rated", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ride_number = models.ForeignKey(Ride, related_name="rider", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And my views

```
def user_view(request):
    avg = user_avg
    total = user_count

    context = {
        'avg': avg,
        'total': total
    }

    return render(request, 'rating/home.html', context)

def user_avg():
    avg = (Rating.objects
                    .values('user_rated').annotate(Avg('stars'))
                    .distinct())

    return avg
```

and lastly my template looks like this

```
  {% for rating in avg %}
  {{ avg }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Right now it renders like this;

```
[{'user_rated': 1L, 'stars__avg': 3.2222}, {'user_rated': 2L, 'stars__avg': 3.625}] [{'user_rated': 1L, 'stars__avg': 3.2222}, {'user_rated': 2L, 'stars__avg': 3.625}]
```

I've tried changing the template to `{{ avg.user_rated }}` but then it renders me nothing, so I'm not sure what im doing wrong here. And how do I get the name of the users avg rating instead of user_rated

Comment: You iterate through `avg`, but then print `avg` itself rather than the loop variable `rating`.

Answer (score 2):

This line in your template:

```
{{ avg }}
```

should be changed to:

```
{{ rating.user_rated }}: {{ rating.stars__avg }}
```

full template:

```
{% for rating in avg %}
{{ rating.user_rated }}: {{ rating.stars__avg }}
{% endfor %}
```

Your 2 errors: 1 - loop var is `rating` - you should use it to access data in loop, 2 - to access data in dict you should use dot notation, check docs.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#variables

> Dictionary lookup, attribute lookup and list-index lookups are
>   implemented with a dot notation:
>
> ```
> {{ my_dict.key }}
> {{ my_object.attribute }}
> {{ my_list.0 }}
> ```

To get user name in results of annotation you should add it to values in query:

```
# assuming that your UserProfile model have name field
avg = (Rating.objects.values(
    'user_rated', 'user_rated__name').annotate(Avg('stars')).distinct())
```

But be careful with `values` and annotations - order is matter and resulting values is depend on values list:

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses

> As with the filter() clause, the order in which annotate() and
>   values() clauses are applied to a query is significant. If the
>   values() clause precedes the annotate(), the annotation will be
>   computed using the grouping described by the values() clause.

Answer (score 1):

`avg` is an array of `Rating` objects, which is exactly what you're seeing in the render. Try `{{ rating.user_rated }}`.

In answer to your second question, you need to join the `Rating` table with the `UserProfile` and `User` tables, assuming that the `User` table contains the users' names. See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for how to do that.